# Apache Spark RDD sortByKey algorithm and time complexity

Tags: apache-spark, time-complexity, big-o, rdd

What is the Big-O time complexity for Apache Spark RDD sortByKey?

I am trying to assign row numbers to an RDD based on a particular order.

Say I have a {K,V} pair RDD and I wish to perform an order by key using

```
myRDD.sortByKey(true).zipWithIndex
```

What is the time complexity for this operation, in big-O form?

And what is happening under-the-covers?  Bubble sort?  I hope not!  My dataset is very large and runs across partitions, so I'm curious whether the sortByKey function is optimal, or does some kind of intermediate data structure within a partition and then something else across partitions to optimize message passing, or what.

Comment: There are additional helpful comments here:  http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Complexity-Efficiency-of-SortByKey-td14328.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at the code shows that a RangePartitioner is being used under the covers. The docs say:

> partitions sortable records by range into roughly
>    * equal ranges. The ranges are determined by sampling the content of the RDD passed in

So in essence your data is sampled (O[n]), then only the unique sample keys (m) are sorted are sorted (O[m log(m)]) and ranges of keys determined, then the entire data is shuffled around (O[n], but costly), then the data sorted internally for the range of keys received on a given partition (O[p log[p)).

`zipWithIndex` probably uses local sizes to assign numbers, using the partition number, so it is likely that partition metadata is stored for this effect:

> Zips this RDD with its element indices. The ordering is first based on the partition index
>      * and then the ordering of items within each partition. So the first item in the first
>      * partition gets index 0, and the last item in the last partition receives the largest index.

Comment: I am not convinced that speaking in terms of the big O notation is justified here. The whole idea behind describing time complexity this way is that we can define _elementary operations_ which have constant execution time. In distributed context we can no longer assume anything like this.

Comment: So, Daniel, is the total time complexity approximately O(NlogN)?  Just curious how the RangePartitioner compares the sorted-within-partition data and shuffles efficiently.  Worse case it might have to compare partitions pair-wise, so might we have an extra factor of p or p^2 ?

Comment: It is in a sense that is not affected by data locality. Lets say you want to add two n-digit numbers. It is simply O(N) operation which always succeeds. In case of distribute system a) it may or may not succeed b) cost of the operation can vary multiple orders of magnitude depending on data locality. In some sense it is still a constant factor, but... c) Non local operation requires serialization, transfer and deserialization -  none of these is accounted above.

Comment: @zero323, you may be right about distributed context removing assumptions, but I think we can still calculate "worse-case" time complexity in big O notation.  If I have N rows of data distributed in reverse-order or random order across P partitions, we wish to know the max time

Comment: I think both of you are right. I agree with @zero323 that the added burden and complexity makes things no-trivial, especially since some "constants" are BIG as far a processing time goes (I specifically mentioned shuffles as one example). O(N logN) is indeed an upper bound I believe for reasoning purposes, but you have to take your reasoning to a more detailed level in terms of distributed-system concepts (data locality, disk and network speeds, etc).

Comment: @GlennStrycker It is just a model and all models are wrong, right? My only point here is that even if you assume zero network latency and lack of failures you have to be really careful and you cannot discard factors like network topology. Lets assume O(N) for shuffle and increase number of network hops between nodes by one. How does it affect our estimation? Truth be told I have no idea.

Comment: I would agree with @zero323 that *time* complexity is not applicable to distributed computations, where shuffling and waiting are random variables. Though seeing an answer what is *computational* complexity could be interesting.